# Bold/Unbold button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working with an online text editor as part of a project, and to say the least, I'm having a small issue with my bold button.

Here is my button in HTML:

```
 <button id="b" onclick="bold()">Bold</button>
```

And here is my function in JavaScript:

```
    function bold() {
      var ban = document.getElementById("b");

      if (ban == true) {
        document.getElementById("texto").style.fontWeight = 'bold';
      } else {
        document.getElementById("texto").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      }
    }
```

If I take away everything and just leave it as:

```
     function bold() {
       document.getElementById("texto").style.fontWeight = 'bold';
     }
```

It makes my text bold, but my goal is to be able to unbold the text inside my `<textarea>` when I click the button a second time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you see when you step through your code in the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Bold() 
{
 
   var  ban =document.getElementById("texto").style.fontWeight ;
 
 if(ban == 'normal')
    {
        document.getElementById("texto").style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }
 else
    {
        document.getElementById("texto").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="b"   onclick="Bold()">Bold</button>

<p id="texto" style="font-weight:normal;">Hi</p>
```

Comment: `Element.style` properties are not accessible for reading on all Browsers. Bad technique.

Comment: @PHPglue http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontweight.asp see the page .all main browsers are supporting

Comment: They also claim you can get the `Element.style.width` like that, as well, but it reality land that doesn't work on some Browsers. See Getting style information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Getting_style_information) . w3schools can help, but is not always fully reliable. Although I do admit this technique may work on many new Browsers, I still don't recommend it.

Comment: @PHPglue Leaving aside the question of whether this is the best approach or not, on which browsers are `element.style` properties not available for reading?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Bold()
{
    var text = document.getElementById("texto");
    var weight = text.style.fontWeight;
    if(weight == 'bold')
    {
        text.style.fontWeight = 'normal';

    }
    else
    {
        text.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use external JavaScript, so it's cached, for quicker load times, and because you should separate your HTML from JavaScript as a best practice. But really, your problem is that you are redefining your `var ban` each time your function is getting called. Watch and learn:

```
//<![CDATA[
// change the pre var on any page using this onload technique
var pre = onload, doc, bod, htm, E, boldToggle; // higher scope in case other onloads need access
onload = function(){ // same as window.onload - note that window is implicit
if(pre)pre(); // execute previous onload

doc = document, bod = doc.body, htm = doc.documentElement;
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
boldToggle = (function(){ // Anonymous function executes and scopes off var b before returning an unexecuted function
  var b = 0; 
  return function(e){ // e is for Element here - this is function that is returned unexecuted
    var s = e.style;
    if(b){ // test if bold
      s.fontWeight = 'normal'; b = 0;
    }
    else{
      s.fontWeight = 'bold'; b = 1;
    }
  }
})();
E('b').onclick = function(){
  boldToggle(this); // this within Event refers to Element id='b' in this case
}

} // end onload
//]]>
```

Oh, if using `<button>` that would be a submit button, so do this:

```
<button type='button' id='b'>Bold</button>
```

I prefer:

```
<input type='button' id='b' value='Bold' />
```

It's more clear, since many a Browser cannot access `.innerHTML` on `<button>` because it's really an input, so the `<button>` tag may be misleading. I learned this when I corrected some code here, where the user had nested other Elements within `<button>`. That won't work on some Browsers, so I just prefer `<input type='button' />`. If you ever work on large projects this can prevent others from trying to throw Elements in there that don't belong.

Comment: *you should separate your HTML from JavaScript* What about separating your CSS from your HTML and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Use classes to manage CSS styling.

```js
function bold() { document.getElementById('b').classList.toggle('bold'); }
```

```css
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<button id="b" onclick="bold()">Bold</button>
```